# Hibernate computed property and SQL queries

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I've implemented a computed property to my configuration which works fine if I'm using HQL only. Sadly there are places where SQL queries are executed which I can't build into HQL. Am I facing a bug or just doing something wrong?

```
<property name="customerNr" type="int" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false">
<formula>
(SELECT DISTINCT p.CUSTOMER FROM P.P03 p WHERE p.COUNTRY = land)
</formula>
</property>
```

When a SQL query is executed, which is done by this way:

```
session.createSQLQuery(queryString).addEntity(P11.class).list()
```

I receive a `NullPointerException`.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.intern(DefaultEntityAliases.java:157)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.getSuffixedPropertyAliases(DefaultEntityAliases.java:130)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.(DefaultEntityAliases.java:76)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.ColumnEntityAliases.(ColumnEntityAliases.java:40)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.generateCustomReturns(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:197)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.(SQLCustomQuery.java:152)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:67)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:136)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:160)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
>           at de.acocon.mis.dao.AmpelDaoImpl.getAmpelOMK(AmpelDaoImpl.java:134)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must copy the formula into your native SQL query. Hibernate doesn't try to manipulate or understand native SQL, when you use it, you're on your own.

Comment: Ok I see, my SQL Queries fetching all columns. Atm I dunno how to implement the formula into my native SQL. Maybe someone can point me the way?

Comment: Ok, I've implemented my formula into the native SQL query, result is the same: nullpointer.